# How to make collapse show and hidden if click to again

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, tabs

My project is in angular 2. I make tabs collapse, I want my collapse hidden if button click again but made from data dynamic or looping:

**My html Code :**

```
  <button (click)="item = 1" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" class="btn mr-3">tab 1</button>
  <button (click)="item = 2" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" class="btn">tab 2</button>

  <div class="collapse" [class.show]="item === 1">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos cumque voluptate dolorem tenetur nesciunt!
  </div>
  <div class="collapse" [class.show]="item === 2">
      Tempora iure porro incidunt laboriosam earum nesciunt repellendus culpa, iste doloribus provident aut, ipsam,
      consectetur quam!
  </div>
```

Comment: Check the answers here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467248/animation-on-angular-4-doesnt-seem-to-have-transition-effect

Comment: see https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngif-and-ngswitch/

Answer (score 1):

If it is just showing and hiding data try [ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

```
<div *ngIf="condition; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
<ng-template #thenBlock>Content to render when condition is true.</ng-template>
<ng-template #elseBlock>Content to render when condition is false.</ng-template>
```

If you need to add or remove a class try [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

```
[ngClass]="{'show': item == 1}"
```

Answer (score 1):

[working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anser-demo-b9ac7a)

You can use `[class]` attribute in angular to achieve this

**Html**

```
 <button (click)="item = 1" [class] ="item===1? 'navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right btn mr-3 btn btn-info' : 'navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right btn mr-3'" type="button" >tab 1</button>
  <button (click)="item = 2" [class] ="item===2? 'navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right btn mr-3 btn btn-info' : 'navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right btn mr-3'" type="button" >tab 2</button>

  <div [class]="item == 1? 'collapse': ''">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos cumque voluptate dolorem tenetur nesciunt!
  </div>
  <div  [class]="item == 2? 'collapse': ''">
    Tempora iure porro incidunt laboriosam earum nesciunt repellendus culpa, iste doloribus provident aut, ipsam,
    consectetur quam!
  </div>
```

**in .ts**

```
item = 1;
```

hope this will helps ...!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it just by replacing `[class.show]` with `*ngIf`

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ljnclg?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
  <div class="collapse" *ngIf="item == 1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos cumque voluptate dolorem tenetur nesciunt!
  </div>
  <div class="collapse" *ngIf="item == 2">
    Tempora iure porro incidunt laboriosam earum nesciunt repellendus culpa, iste doloribus provident aut, ipsam,
    consectetur quam!
  </div>
```

Note: if you want to show the first tab by default, set `item=1` in .ts file